# Defining a vector with variables (as if it were a function)

Tags: vector

I would like to define a vector with variables that can be inputed later.  For instance, I would want to define some vector v = {v1, v2}, use it in some operations and then, much later, tell it what v1 and v2 are.  How can I do this?

As an analogy, I could define a function f[x_,y_]:=2x+y and later tell mathematica what x and y are.  But when I try to do the natural analogue for a vector---which I would have guessed is v[v1_,v2_]:= {v1, v2}---I get errors.

(I am sure this must be very basic, but I cannot find the right article.)

Comment: Try `Clear[v]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that you missed the `SetDelayed`.

```
v[a_, b_] := {a, b}
```

If you evaluate `v[1, 2]`, you could get `{1, 2}`.

Comment: Sorry, I must be misunderstanding what you are saying.  When I copied and pasted what you wrote, I got an error.  When I googled, I kept getting SetDelayed is :=.  I certainly inadvertently wrote "=" instead of ":=" in my original post, but I meant ":=" and have been getting errors with  v[v1_,v2_]:= {v1, v2}.  But probably I am misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: @Amanda Can you please try the following? First Clear[v]. Then v[a_, b_] := {a, b} and finally v[1, 2]. The result after the final command is {1,2} on my laptop without any errors

Comment: Ah, yes, when I clear it does work!  Thanks!